# How to pass Decodable.protocol as a function parameter from structs property?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a struct Endpoint

```
struct Endpoint {
    let responseDecodable: Decodable.Type
    let path: String
    let queryItems: [URLQueryItem]
}
```

which is used to construct different api requests using Alamofire:

```
func fetchData(_ endpoint: Endpoint) {
        AF.request(endpoint.url!).responseDecodable(of: endpoint.responseDecodable) { response in
            
        }
    }
```

```
extension Endpoint {
    static func getUser(by id: Int) -> Endpoint {
        return Endpoint(
            responseDecodable: UsersGet.self,
            path: ... ,
            queryItems: ... )
    }
    static func getFriends(by user: User) -> Endpoint {
        return Endpoint(
            responseDecodable: FriendsGet.self,
            path: ... ,
            queryItems: ... )
    }
```

The problem is, different endpoint requests give different JSON objects, and I need to specify that type in `responseDecodable(of: Decodable.Protocol)`

But AF.request in `func fetchData` gives me an error: **Cannot convert value of type 'Decodable.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'**
How do I pass that `Decodable.Protocol` from `Endpoint` without making a generic struct?

Comment: But isn't this a very good use case for generics?

Comment: Is there any reason to dont use generic struct for this?

Comment: I kinda want that the type is known after endpoint is constructed, not placing that info in the function parameters, simply looks more beautiful. And im still learning as well so I'm just interested is this possible at all. I feel like im not understanding this `.type` `.self` kind of things with protocols and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back I see that was a silly question but hey
Generic struct that returns type in the endpoint constructor solves the problem.

```
struct Endpoint<T> where T: Decodable {
    let path: String
    let queryItems: [URLQueryItem]
}

extension Endpoint {
    static func getUser(by id: Int) -> Endpoint<UsersGet> {
        return Endpoint<UsersGet>(
            path: ... ,
            queryItems: ... )
        )
    }
    // same for other endpoints
}
```

And the fetchData function used like this with generic parameter that is automatically inferred (that's what I wanted)

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint<T>, completion: @escaping (DataResponse<T, AFError>) -> Void) {
    AF.request(endpoint.url!).responseDecodable(completionHandler: completion)
}

fetchData(.getFriends(by: user)) { response in
    // ... 
}
```